# Entity Framework code first migrations doesn't pickup changes to the Model classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a new project in Visual Studio 2012 and I have 3 projects:

- TestMVC => An ASP.NET MVC 5 project
- TestContext => A class library project which contains my `TestContext` class which inherits from `DbContext` class.
- TestDomainClasses => A class library project which contains my model classes.

I have created a class in TestDomainClasses project like this:

```
public class Topic
{
    public int ID;
    public string Title;
}
```

And in my `TestContext` class:

```
public DbSet<Topic> Topics;
```

I have also setup a connection string to point to my local SQL Server. Now, I have enabled migrations using the `Enable-Migrations` command.

It created the `Migrations` folder which has a `Configuration.cs` file in it.

Next, I am trying to create an initial migration for creating the `Topic` class:

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration
```

It creates the new migration, but the `up` and `down` methods are empty. I tried adding another property to the `Topic` class and re-run `Add-Migration InitialMigration` again, but it generates an empty migration for me.

I am confused what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you created the Migration folder manually?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add getters and setters to your DbSet declaration.

```
public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
```

I prefer adding the references to the ApplicationDbContext class in the IdentityModels.cs file (in the Models folder)

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

//rest of the stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open package manager console. Tools-->Library Package Manager-->Package Manager Console and use this command in package console Update-Database. ! Make sure to select the correct project.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that an OLD version of my project DLL was installed in the GAC. The add-migration must look at the one in the GAC if it is there. Once I deleted the DLL in the GAC, it picked up my changes in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you need to add the setters/getters to your model